# Where can I practice DELETE, PUT and POST requests. Do some free API exist that allow to do this?

Tags: reactjs, python-requests, axios, frontend, rest

I do not have experience in programming. Now I try to learn React. I found different APIs provided by companies for free. But this way I can practice only GET requests. Because, no one wants me to delete, add or edit on their servers :)

So my question is:

How front end developers can practice DELETE, POST and PUT requests?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from creating your own server-side application, you don't need to rely on external services.  A simple introductory NodeJS back-end would allow you to create and use whatever endpoints you like.  Or you could use any other language/framework/etc., such as Python (since you've somewhat tagged that already).

Answer (score 6):

There are a few websites providing sample API endpoints you can perform DELETE, POST and PUT. See 2 of them below.

https://reqres.in/

https://dummy.restapiexample.com/

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is that you download a local server from MySql and then use your local server along with your IDE and make the requests in your own database